# VBA fails doing calculation on table columns

Tags: vba

```
Sub AddNumbersOnOneRow
  Const s_Field_ColA = "ColumnA"
  Const s_Field_ColB = "ColumnB"
  Const s_Field_ColC = "ColumnC"
  Const s_Field_ColD = "ColumnD"


  Dim iPsDepth As Integer
  Dim iPsColA As Integer
  Dim iPsColB As Integer
  Dim iPsColC As Integer
  Dim iPsColD As Integer

  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim dDepth As Double
  Dim ColumnD As Double
  '------------------------
  'Determine the field positions of the necessary fields in the array.

  If InitFieldsFnB(gs_Depth, iPsDepth, _
                   s_Field_ColA, iPsColA, _
                   s_Field_ColB, iPsColB, _
                   s_Field_ColC, iPsColC) _
  Then
    'One or more of the required fields missing from the table.
    Exit Sub
  End If

  With gINTRules.GridData 

    iPsDepth = .FieldCol("Depth")
    iPsColA = .FieldCol("ColumnA")
    iPsColB = .FieldCol("ColumnB")
    iPsColC = .FieldCol("ColumnC")
    iPsColD = .FieldCol("ColumnD")


    For lRow = 1 To glNumRows
      ColumnD= CDbl(gsDataA(iPsColA, lRow))+ CDbl(gsDataA(iPsColB, lRow))

      gsDataA(iPsColD, lRow)= CStr(ColumnD)

    Next lRow
  End With

End Sub
```

When I run this macro, I didn't get any errors. However, this macro doesn't give me the answer, nothing in column D.

I want to put the addition of column A and ColumnB into columnD
![This is my table, I want to put the addition of column A and ColumnB into columnD. But When I run the macro I get nothing.]

I suspect that the following lines are giving me trouble:

```
For lRow = 1 To glNumRows
      ColumnD= CDbl(gsDataA(iPsColA, lRow))+ CDbl(gsDataA(iPsColB, lRow))

      gsDataA(iPsColD, lRow)= CStr(ColumnD)

Next lRow
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

My main sub is :

```
'#LibInclude "common procedures"

Option Explicit
Public Sub Main
  Dim gsDataA As Variant
  Dim glNumRows As Integer
  With gINTRules.GridData
    'Put the grid data into a working string data array.
    gsDataA = .DataArray
    glNumRows = UBound(gsDataA, 2)

    'Put the modified data array back into the input grid.
    .DataArray = gsDataA
    'Success is True if there were no errors.
    gINTRules.Success = CBool(.ErrorCol = 0)
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you're setting the value somewhere else, glNumRows isn't assigned a value in the code you posted, so it has a default value of 0, which means your loop isn't running at all.

Give glNumRows a value and you should see some results.

Based on your updated question:

The variable glNumRows isn't in the  scope of your AddNumbersOnOneRow sub.  Just as a test, try putting this line before that loop in your AddNumbersOnOneRow sub (I think I have the syntax right, I haven't tested it):

```
glNumRows = UBound(gINTRules.GridData.DataArray, 2)
```

Again, just to reiterate...glNumRows isn't defined in your AddNUmbersOnOneRow sub.  You can add it as a parameter or set it in the sub, or maybe even set it as a global variable if you're feeling really adventurous.

If you don't want to add my code above as a test, you can also set a breakpoint on the line that initializes the loop and check the value of glNumRows and report back what VBA says the value is...my guess is it will tell you it's 0.

Comment: I put glNumRows in Main, but the loop still isn't running

Comment: @user2634156 can you edit your original post to include your updated code?  It's a bear to try and make heads or tails of it as an unformatted comment block.

Comment: thank you. I added that in my code, and I can print out the answer using "MsgBox". However, that answer isn't showing up in my table for some reason.

Comment: I was trying to write the answer to table through this line:                gsDataA(iPsColD, lRow)=CStr(ColumnD)   but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: @user2634156  Hold on...are you sure this is VBA and not VB or VB.net?  Is this an access application your building?